# How do I find out which Research Agreements are active?

Tags: civilization-5

How can I find out which research agreements I, or anybody else, has active? I can't seem to find a screen that has a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the Diplomacy icon (top right) then on the Diplomacy Overview button - it should show on here (on left hand side) if you have any Research Agreements in place.
I dont think there is any way to see other civs Research Agreements, only your own.

Answer (score 2):

The diplomacy overview should have it. Unfortunately, it lists things in a non-intuitive manner (it lists the turn the agreement started on, I believe?) so once you know the start date, you have to calculate the intervening years (and thus the end date) on your own.

Comment: Turn ≠ Year. Just look at the turns, it'll say something like "started at turn 241, for 30 turns". :)

Comment: Yeah, clearly, but I'd prefer it say something like "started at turn 241, for 30 turns. (24/30)"

Comment: Sure, so would I. Just wanted to point out that *dates* (years) don't correlate to *turns*. :)

Comment: Oh, aha. I see where you're taking umbrage now. Ha! Idiomatic time expressions don't mix well when talking about time, I see.